# Dúvida em relação a função for

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<matrizFemininaArryn.length; j++){
             if(mat[i][5].equals("Feminino") && mat[i][4].equals("Arryn")) matrizFemininaArryn[j] = mat[i][0];
            }    
}
```

No exemplo acima, a `matrizFemininaArryn` vai receber a `matriz[i][0]` até preencher seu tamanho completo correto?
No entando meu objetivo era que ao executar o `for` para a primeira posição do vetor `matrizFemininaArryn`, executasse o `for` do `i` novamente, para não aplicar o mesmo resultado na posição seguinte do verto `matrizFemininaArryn`.

Como proceder?

Answer (score 1):

Existem dois comandos que podem ser utilizados para modificar o percurso normal da execução de *loops*: `break` e `continue`

O `break` faz com que o *loop* seja terminado de imediato, continuando a execução a partir da instrução a seguir à chaveta que fecha o código do *loop*.
O código entre o `break` e a chaveta é ignorado.

Este código de exemplo procura pelo numero 12 no *array*. O `break` termina o *loop* quando o valor é encontrado.

```
class BreakDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arrayOfInts = 
            { 32, 87, 3, 589,
              12, 1076, 2000,
              8, 622, 127 };
        int searchfor = 12;

        int i;
        boolean foundIt = false;

        for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            if (arrayOfInts[i] == searchfor) {
                foundIt = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (foundIt) {
            System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at index " + i);
        } else {
            System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

O `continue` faz com que a execução salte para a linha onde se encontra a chaveta que fecha o código do *loop*, fazendo com que a condição dele seja avaliada, o *loop* executará de novo caso ela seja `true`.
O código entre o `continue` e a chaveta é ignorado.

O código do exemplo seguinte percorre a *string* contando todas as ocorrências da letra 'p'. Se a letra analisada não é um 'p' o *continue* faz com que o código seguinte seja ignorado e se passe à letra seguinte.

```
class ContinueDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String searchMe = "peter piper picked a " + "peck of pickled peppers";
        int max = searchMe.length();
        int numPs = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {

            if (searchMe.charAt(i) != 'p')
                continue; // se não é 'p' buscar próxima letra

            // Mais um 'p' encontrado
            numPs++;
        }
        System.out.println("Found " + numPs + " p's in the string.");
    }
}
```

Se entendi bem a sua pergunta o que procura é o `break`. O seu código ficaria assim:

```
for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<matrizFemininaArryn.length; j++){
        if(mat[i][5].equals("Feminino") && mat[i][4].equals("Arryn")){
            matrizFemininaArryn[j] = mat[i][0];
            break;
        }
     }
}//após a execução do break a execução salta para aqui terminado o ciclo 'j'
 //continuando o ciclo 'i'
```

Tanto o `break` como o `continue` actuam em relação ao *loop* onde estão inseridos.
Caso se queira que eles se refiram a *loops* mais exteriores, associa-se a eles um *label* que indica a que *loop* se referem.

Suponha que queria que o seu código terminasse ambos os *loops* quando a condição do `if` fosse verdadeira.
O código seria assim:

```
//Identifica-se o loop com um 'label'
search:
for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<matrizFemininaArryn.length; j++){
        if(mat[i][5].equals("Feminino") && mat[i][4].equals("Arryn")){
            matrizFemininaArryn[j] = mat[i][0];
            break search; //Adicionado o 'label' seach
        }
     }
}
//após a execução do break a execução salta para aqui terminado o ciclo 'j'e o ciclo 'i'
```

<sub>Fonte do código dos exemplos: [Documentação do Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)</sub>